# How to reference UI.Page in a class

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm have a helper class where I want to run a client script using the ScriptManager:

```
public static void HideMessage()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "hideMessage", "hideMessage();", true);
}
```

Except I cannot reference Page as I'm getting the error, "Class name is not valid at this point". I realize that I could pass the Page into the method from the webform code behind. Is there a way to reference the Page without using a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about substituting `Page` with `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, 
    HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.GetType(), 
    "hideMessage", 
    "hideMessage();", 
    true);
```

Comment: He's using a static method, so no this

Comment: @RobinNadeau Thanks for noticing this. He should be able to get a reference to the page through the HttpContext